# Different results when installing with installer

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created an installer with WIX toolset, which is great it installs everything. I have it create a shortcut to .exe file in the application. It does this.

What my issue is, is that when I click the actual .exe file everything in the application works as expected, but when I click the .exe, it starts but not everything loads correctly.

So on to my "Question", Is there a way for me to Debug an installed application from the shortcut?

If not, are there any suggestions that you would recommend for this scenario, as I've never run into this issue before?

Comment: Just a thought, but does your application rely on paths? If so, it could be that Windows is setting the CWD to the directory where the shortcut is located. If your application then relies on files lying in that path, then some things might not work as expected.

Comment: thank you! I will look into this today.